# Verify SSL certificate

Tags: windows, google-chrome, https

I encountered [this error](https://superuser.com/questions/1083766/how-do-i-deal-with-neterr-cert-authority-invalid-in-chrome) on Google Chrome on my Windows10.
I solved by installing the certificate and now is working fine.

How could I be sure the certificate is coming from Google and not from a Man-In-The-Middle, maybe due to some kind of malware for instance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google cert is issued by Google CA. Public cert is available on https://pki.google.com.